# Codeigniter Load model automatically convert first character to lowercase

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my model named `Userhome_model.php`

```
 class Userhome_model extends CI_Model {

    function Userhome_model() {
        parent::__construct();
```

I tried to call this in my controller like

```
   this->load->model('Userhome_model');
```

But i got an error like

> *Unable to locate the model you have specified: userhome_model*

Comment: Is your `Userhome_model.php` in the correct directory?

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: yes. Its inside **model**

Comment: Use `public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
        }` to define constructor

Comment: i changed that too. The naming of file and its call confusing me. Its worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to

```
this->load->model('Userhome_model');
```

this

```
this->load->model('userhome_model');
```

this will fix the issue([How to load model](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model))

---

and Model should be place inside **`application/model`**

---

File Name - ***userhome_model.php***

Inside **`userhome_model`**

```
class Userhome_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

---

**Using model**

```
this->model_name->method();
```

Comment: Its worked for me. But For my previous project the naming of model was first letter capital and its worked for me that time. Its hosted in the same server.

Comment: Its changed on CI V3.0+

Comment: @ManeeshMS happy to help. Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: Thanx for the help. :)

Comment: But when I refer the CI3 documentation I found     application/models/User_model.php This how they suggest to give the name of the model like[this](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Comment: check this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: yes its correct. I am refering the name of the file

Comment: I think you are right. The file name also should be lowercase. When changed the first charter to uppercase the error again come up

Comment: ya defantly. it should